# Technique to debug CSS interference with custom HTML in WordPress Sites

Tags: html, css, wordpress, parallax

I'm working on a custom HTML block that creates a multi-layer parallax effect for a feature image in my WordPress site. I got the code mostly working in a code example (see below)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}   

  .parallax_layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    }

  #parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: audo;
  }

    .cover {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        left: 50% !important;
        transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
    }

  .parallax__layer--front {
        transform: translateZ(0);
  }

  .parallax__layer--middle {
        transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
        transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
  }

  .parallax__layer--base {
        transform: translateZ(-3px) scale(4);
  }
```

```html
    <div id="parallax" class="cover">
        <img class="parallax_layer parallax__layer--base" src="https://www.staging7.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Blue-mountains-background.png">
        <img class="parallax_layer parallax__layer--back" src="https://www.staging7.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/circle-in-sky.png">
    <img class="parallax_layer parallax__layer--middle" src="https://www.staging7.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Airport.png">
        <img class="parallax_layer parallax__layer--front" src="https://www.staging7.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Gold-ribbon.png">
        <img class="parallax_layer parallax__layer--front" src="https://www.staging7.midstory.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Airplane.png">
    </div>
```

but when I port it over to the WordPress post, the parallax effect doesn't work anymore.

I've had things like this happen before and it usually turns into a wile goose chase to figure out what CSS is interfering with my code to remove/override it. My typical approach is to use the developer console to disable other CSS classes that are applying style settings to the element in question, and this usually works most of the time, but it's harder to track other settings that may be from parent elements in the DOM.

Does anyone know of any good, more systematic ways/techniques/tools to track down and troubleshoot CSS interference issues in WordPress?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand why using your browser's dev tools inspect facility would't give you everything you need. If you look at the styles applied to those elements you should be able to see where the 'overwriting' styles are coming from. Is that not the case?

Comment: My question mainly concerns the technique more than the tools. I believe the dev tools console has everything I need to use. But I'm always looking for better/more efficient approaches to debug things.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, in this particular case, there actually wasn't a problem with WordPress preventing the parallax effect from working. It is a different issue, which I outlined in this post on the same code sample:

[Trouble with scrolling multi-layer parallax effect for cover graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817301/trouble-with-scrolling-multi-layer-parallax-effect-for-cover-graphic)